# I don't know my @icloud.com address

Tags: icloud, apple-id

Someone stole my iPad and I got it back. Now the device is requesting for activation using @icloud.com address which I can't remember setting up.

Though I still have my Apple ID login details but can't use it to log in. I tried using my Apple ID, but it didn't work, I logged into [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com), but could not see the @icloud.com address. I requested Apple for my data, but still couldn't find the @icloud.com address.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Take it to an Apple Store with your receipt for buying it.